# Why doesn't my dice loop work?

Tags: python, class, loops

I need my code to loop 5 random numbers through a class. In the IDLE program it just keeps infinitely going and doesn't stop but I cant seem to find the issue with my code.

```
from random import randint
x = 0
while x < 6:
    class Dice(object):
            def __init__(self):
                    self.dice = []
                    self.dice.append(str(randint(1,6)))
                    x += 1


hand = Dice() # Creates a Dice object
print hand.dice # Prints the instance variable dice (5 random numbers)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` loop only defines a class, but it doesn't actually evaluate any code. In particular, it doesn't increase `x`, so it's an infinite loop.

I think you probably want that `while` loop in the constructor, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining a class object in a loop. Defining a class will not execute the `__init__` method defined in it.

This is apart from the fact that the `x` variable in the `__init__` method is a local, independent from the global `x` tested for in the `while` loop.

Put the loop *in the `__init__` method* so that it is run when creating an instance of the `Dice` class:

```
from random import randint

class Dice(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.dice = []
        x = 0
        while x < 6:
            self.dice.append(str(randint(1,6)))
            x += 1

hand = Dice() # Creates a Dice object
print hand.dice # Prints the instance variable dice (5 random numbers)
```